# Playing an MP4 using Swift in IOS

Tags: swift

It seems an easy task, but once again I find myself at a loss for solving.  Here is the code.  It comes back that it 'found video', but just displays a white screen. Help!:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import AVFoundation
import MediaPlayer
import AVKit

 class SampleView: UIViewController {
var sw: CGFloat = 0;
var sh: CGFloat = 0;
var hw: CGFloat = 0;

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
     if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: theImage, ofType: "mp4") {
        print("found video")
        let videoURL = URL(string: filePath)
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
     } else{print("no found video")}
```

Comment: `viewDidLoad` is too early to present a view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You need to move code to `viewDidAppear` as in `viewDidLoad` view's hierarchy is not yet complete to present any VC

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated:Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
     if let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: theImage, ofType: "mp4") {
        print("found video")
        let videoURL = URL(string: filePath)
        let player = AVPlayer(url: videoURL!)
        let playerViewController = AVPlayerViewController()
        playerViewController.player = player
        self.present(playerViewController, animated: true) {
            playerViewController.player!.play()
        }
     } else{print("no found video")
}
```